# Java detect if a string is a valid JS script

Tags: java, javascript

I want to detect if a string is a valid javasript code for pass it for the evaluation of rhino engine, now i'm assuming that the string is a javascript script with this simple statement :

```
if(jsString.trim().endsWith(";")) {
//Evaluate with Rhino
}
```

Is there a better way for figure out if a string is a valid JS script ?

What is the best way ?

Comment: What do you mean by "valid JS script"? Pass it to Rhino and if it works, it's valid.

Comment: Cant you just pass it in and catch any exception if it fails and then handle it from there?

Comment: See also the `ScriptEngine`.  Example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7441625/how-to-find-a-button-source-in-awt-calculator-homework/7441804#7441804).

Comment: `jsString.trim().endsWith(";")` BTW - AFAIU a single line script does not need a trailing `;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could utilise something like: http://code.google.com/p/jslint4java/

In any case, you want to run the string through JSLint.